# Group result conversation id into one <div> tag

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've a chat table, I want to put messages into one div tag for each conversation id or `conv_id` row.

**here's my chat table:**
[image]

---

**Here's my php code:**

```
<?php
require 'config/config.php';
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
$from = 6;
$to = 3;

$stmt_msg = $conn->prepare("
SELECT * 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT id
            , message
            , from_id
            , to_id
            , conv_id 
         FROM chat 
        WHERE (from_id = ? AND to_id = ?) 
           OR (to_id = ? AND from_id = ?)
        ORDER 
           BY send_date desc LIMIT 20
      ) as tmp 
  ORDER 
     BY tmp.id
");
$stmt_msg->bind_param("iiii", $to, $from, $to, $from);
if ($stmt_msg->execute()) {
    $query_gmsgs = $stmt_msg->get_result();
    if (mysqli_num_rows($query_gmsgs) > 0) {
 
        while ($rowmsg = $query_gmsgs->FETCH_ARRAY()) {
                $message = htmlspecialchars($rowmsg['message']);
                $to_id = htmlspecialchars($rowmsg['to_id']);
                $from_id = htmlspecialchars($rowmsg['from_id']);
                $send_date = htmlspecialchars($row['send_date']);
                $send_datev = date_create($send_date);
                $send_datev = date_format($send_datev, 'd/m/y');
                $conv_id = htmlspecialchars($rowmsg['conv_id']);
                
                if($from_id == $from){
                    echo "<div class='from $conv_id'><p>Me: $message</p></div>"; 
                }else{
                    echo "<div class='to $conv_id'><p>Other: $message</p></div>";
                }
        }
}
}
?>
```

**Here's Result show in the web browser:**
[image]

As you see, We've multiple `<div>` tag for `conv_id` for each Message have a `<div>` tag. I want to Group each Conversation to one div.
**For Example:**
the Message 1 and 2 have two messages sent by User 6, which have 6-1 conv_id. I want to group those messages [1, 2] to one div. and so on. thanks. by the way **I want this**:
[image]

Comment: These screenshots really do nothing to help your question. They're just taking up a ton of space. Some plain-text HTML describing your desired outcome is considerably easier to work with than a screenshot of same. If you need to group things together, consider using `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY` on your results.

Comment: @tadman Send a fixable code How?

Comment: May I know why do you want to show (or order)  it that way?

Comment: Just type regular HTML into your question with code formatting. The screenshot of the inspector is not as useful, we can't copy-paste that and use it in answers, it's just pixels.

Comment: @tadman I don't have a regular HTML. just I have php and mysql. the php is into my q, as you see. that pictures to understand my question because my English so bad to understand developers. sorry

Comment: @tcadidot0 Becouse I want to for each messages have a div to show sender name or recover name., such as: Snapchat. like: John: messages, ME: messages .. so on

Comment: Rather than having the superquery, you could just use array_sort to rearrange the result set by id

Comment: What tadman means is that you could just post the codes in alphanumeric form like your php code above instead of posting photos; because it will be easier for others to copy your codes if they need to replicate your situation. P/S: the third and fourth photo in your question is HTML .. you even have `<html>` tag in there

Answer (score 0):

You can do an order by `conv_id` then:

```
$prev="";
while(//loop over your query result)
{
$new = $conv_id;//your conv_id
if($new != $prev){
if($prev != ""){
    echo '</div>';
    }
echo '<div>';
$prev=$new;
}
//echo your message in p tags here



}
```